# How to concatenate 3 NSData variables

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

How to concatenate 3 `NSData` variables ?

```
NSData *iv;
NSData *salt;
NSData *encryptedData;
```

I need to join these to a single variable. Can any one show me a way.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

use an `NSMutableData` object and the method `-(void)appendData:(NSData *)otherData`

Edited to add example :

```
NSMutableData *concatenatedData = [NSMutableData data];
[concatenatedData appendData:iv];
[concatenatedData appendData:salt];
[concatenatedData appendData:encryptedData];
// and now you have all of the data in the single variable "concatenatedData"
```

Comment: How to retrieve particular data from the NSMutableData.

Comment: @VineeshTPthe concatenatedData IS the mutable data.

Answer (score 4):

For those who coding for iOS5 and later.
I'd like to show some real good concatenation. Why are those answers aren't good enough? Because they are involves extra memory usage for copied data. Let's see the answer:

```
NSMutableData *concatenatedData = [NSMutableData data];
[concatenatedData appendData:iv];
[concatenatedData appendData:salt];
[concatenatedData appendData:encryptedData];
```

here we have memory allocated for `iv`, `salt` and `encryptedData`
also each time we append one of them to our mutable concatenation we are obviously copy it to mutable data again. Do we want this extra expenses while dealing with large data? Me not.

There is a way to avoid this unnecessary expense of memory - `dispatch_data`
I'm not going to explain how it works, you can google it if you want.
I just give you a code that works:

```
NSData *iv = [@"some data" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *salt = [@"even more data" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *encryptedData = [@"and one more" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);
dispatch_data_t dispatch_data_iv = dispatch_data_create([iv bytes], [iv length], queue, DISPATCH_DATA_DESTRUCTOR_DEFAULT);
dispatch_data_t dispatch_data_salt = dispatch_data_create([salt bytes], [salt length], queue, DISPATCH_DATA_DESTRUCTOR_DEFAULT);
dispatch_data_t dispatch_data_encrypted = dispatch_data_create([encryptedData bytes], [encryptedData length], queue, DISPATCH_DATA_DESTRUCTOR_DEFAULT);
iv = nil; salt = nil; encryptedData = nil; // free all parts, we dont need it anymore
dispatch_data_t dispatch_data_concat = dispatch_data_create_concat( dispatch_data_create_concat(dispatch_data_iv, dispatch_data_salt), dispatch_data_encrypted);
NSData *concatenatedNSData = DataFromDispatchData(dispatch_data_concat);

// lets check now if the concatenation works properly
NSString *stringFromConcatenatedNSData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:concatenatedNSData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",stringFromConcatenatedNSData);
```

don't forget about the helper-converter

```
NSData *DataFromDispatchData(dispatch_data_t data)
{
    NSMutableData *result = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: dispatch_data_get_size(data)];
    dispatch_data_apply(data, ^(dispatch_data_t region, size_t offset, const void *buffer, size_t size) {
        [result appendBytes:buffer length:size];
        return (_Bool)true;
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I smell pre-mature optimization. If other codes are good enough but still better readable they should be preferred.

Comment: That's a lot of code for concatenating 3 variables.

Comment: @quantumpotato depends on how much memory the variables use

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSMutableData`'s [`-appendData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableData/appendData%3a) method:

```
NSMutableData *result = [NSMutableData data];

[result appendData:iv];
[result appendData:salt];
[result appendData:encryptedData];

// result now has what you need.
```

This comes at the overhead of using mutable data, which can be slower & use more memory, so use with care. Generally speaking you don't want large `NSData`'s floating around.

Answer (score -3):

First create two `NSObjects` and use this method

```
-(void)appendData:(NSData *)otherData
```

and put in one `NSData` later with 3rd `NSData` also concatenate with the same method.

Comment: Thanks for ur help. But am new to iphone and am little comfused.. Can u please give me the code to join these three NSData.. Thanks in advance